# Move files to a network drive via batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, networking, network-drive

I have a network drive and I'd like to move some files on it via the windows task scheduler however I have some trouble making the batch file.

```
start "" "C:\PATH_TO_7z\7za.exe" a -tzip D:\Backup.zip D:\*.xlsx
Pause
move "D:\Backup.zip" "\\HostName\ShareName"
Pause
```

The move command say that he cannot find the network name.

I've tried to use `net use` like

```
net use S: "\\HostName\ShareName"
```

And here it says `error 67` and he still cannot find the network name too.

However I succeed to move files with the same command line when I use it from the CMD and not from a batch file (I tried to run batch file as admin too).

So my question is, how can I map this drive within the script and then move my files in the drive ?

EDIT: I did a bit of testing and found out that when I run a windows CMD as an admin `net use` does not see my network drive but when I run a CMD normally I did see the disk.

Comment: `move "D:\Backup.zip" "\\NETWORK\DRIVE` is missing a terminating `"` ...

Comment: Oh, I just missed it here, fixed

Comment: You really need the `start` command?  Is 7za.exe a GUI app?

Comment: Well, I just tested it and seems like I don't need the `start` command, I'm not used to windows command line so I just went with that.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `ERROR_BAD_NET_NAME`.  The correct pattern is `\\HostName\ShareName`. If you can't remove the `start` command from the script, then add the`/WAIT` option to its command line.  It's possible you are witnessing a race for access to the zip file.

Comment: Well my pattern is the one `net use` is showing and I believe it's the same pattern as you mentionned: `\\mylap\mydrive4`

What I do not understand is the fact that, when I use the command 
`move "D:\Backup.zip" "\\HostName\ShareName"`directly in the CMD it works just fine but it does not when I use it from a batch file.

Answer (score 0):

This was failing for me and it was because the hostname is case sensitive. Hope this helps someone